# Confusion about differential of multivariable functions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have been given a function $F: \mathbb{R²} \to \mathbb{R³}$

and another function $\beta: J \to \mathbb{R³}: t \mapsto F(a + tx)$

where $x = v_1(1,0) + v_2(0,1) = (v_1,v_2)$ and $a$ is fixed. we can assume that all given functions are differentiable on their domain.

I'm asked to find $\beta'(0)$ (this should be equal to $D_1F(a)v_1 + D_2F(a)v_2$)

**My attempt:**

Let $R(t) = a+tx$

Then $\beta'(0) = D\beta(0) = D(F\circ R)(0) = DF(R(0)) \circ DR(0)$

and then I'm stuck.

Comment: What you did is correct. Next expand $DF(R(0))$ and $DR(0)$ by using definition.

Comment: I'm not sure what definition you mean.

Comment: The differential of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ at a point $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear map $Df(c) : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\left\|f(c+h) - f(c) - Df(c)h\right\|}{\|h\|} = 0$$

Comment: Can't I use the relation with the jacobians somehow?

Comment: The Jacobian is precisely the matrix representation of the differential operator. So $\circ$ in the expression $DF(R(0)) \circ DR(0)$ could be interpreted as a composition of linear maps, or as multiplication of respective Jacobians.

Comment: So you claim that $DF(R(0)) \circ DR(0) = JF(R(0)) . JR(0)$?

Comment: Yes, but the left hand side is a linear map, and the right hand side is the matrix which represents it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R(t)=(R_{1}(t),R_{2}(t)):=(a_{1}+tx_{1},a_{2}+tx_{2})$, and $\beta=F\circ R$, so $\beta'(0)=\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}(R(0))R_{1}'(0)+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}(R(0))R_{2}'(0)$. Note that $R_{1}'(0)=x_{1}$ and $R_{2}'(0)=x_{2}$.

Here $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}=D_{1}F$ and similar to $D_{2}F$.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a basic question but how do you arrive at those steps starting from my attempt? Is my attempt even correct?

Comment: Essentially what you wrote is correct, but that means matrix multiplication, can you expand the so called $DR(0)$?

Comment: What do you mean expand on DR(0)?

Comment: $DR(0)$ can be represented as a matrix, the so called Jacobian, do you know what entries are they?

Comment: Yes, $$JR(0) = \begin{pmatrix} D_1 R_1(0) \\ D_1 R_2(0) \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes, then you are done, why get stuck?

Comment: What I wrote are linear transformations, what is the connection with the matrices in this context? (I know with every matrix corresponds a linear transformation and so on, and multiplication corresponds with composition)

Comment: As what you have said, linear maps in finite dimensional correspond uniquely with the matrices in the standard bases, which in this case, the Jacobian matrices will do, and the composition is right the matrix multiplication. If you expand the Jacobian of $F$ and multiply with the Jacobian of $R$, the equation is exactly what I have written down.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you claim $DF(R(0)) \circ DR(0) = JF(R(0)) . JR(0)$? Because this doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Yes, and actually $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}=(\dfrac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial x})$ and so my $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}R_{1}'(0)$ is interpreted as coordinates, so the final result would be $(\dfrac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x}R_{1}'(0)+\dfrac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y}R_{2}'(0),\dfrac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x}R_{1}'(0)+\dfrac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y}R_{2}'(0),\dfrac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial x}R_{1}'(0)+\dfrac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial y}R_{2}'(0))$

Answer (score 0):

You're almost done.

The differential of an affine function $x \mapsto Ax + b$ where $A$ is a linear map and $b$ is a vector is equal to the linear map $A$. Indeed:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|(Ah + b) - (A\cdot 0 + b) - Ah\|}{\|h\|} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|Ah + b - Ah - b\|}{\|h\|} = 0$$
Hence, we have $DR(0) = x\cdot$, the operator of multiplication by $x$.

$DF(R(0))$ is just $DF(a)$, since $R(0) = a$.

So, $D\beta(0) = DF(a) \,\circ x\cdot$.